# How can I implement a growing bar in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a heat bar which grows every time I press 'x' and I can't figure out how. What can I do?

```
heatBar = [45, 30]

elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_x:
                for pos in heatBar:
                    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, GREEN,(pos[0],pos[1],10,50))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an `area` argument to [`Surface.blit`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit). The `area` has to be a [rect](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) or rect-style tuple (x_coord, y_coord, width, height) and allows you to control the visible area of the surface. So if you have a surface that is 150 pixels wide and pass a rect with a width of 100, then the surface will only be rendered up to the 100 pixel border.

Now just use the `heat` value (which is the percentage of the image width) to calculate the current width, `heat_rect.w/100*heat`, and pass it to the `blit` method.

```
import pygame as pg


pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
BG_COLOR = pg.Color(30, 30, 50)

HEAT_BAR_IMAGE = pg.Surface((150, 20))
color = pg.Color(0, 255, 0)
# Fill the image with a simple gradient.
for x in range(HEAT_BAR_IMAGE.get_width()):
    for y in range(HEAT_BAR_IMAGE.get_height()):
        HEAT_BAR_IMAGE.set_at((x, y), color)
    if color.r < 254:
        color.r += 2
    if color.g > 1:
        color.g -= 2


def main():
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    heat_rect = HEAT_BAR_IMAGE.get_rect(topleft=(200, 100))
    # `heat` is the percentage of the surface's width and
    # is used to calculate the visible area of the image.
    heat = 5  # 5% of the image are already visible.
    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True

        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pg.K_x]:
            heat += 4  # Now 4% more are visible.

        heat -= 1  # Reduce the heat every frame.
        heat = max(1, min(heat, 100))  # Clamp the value between 1 and 100.

        screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
        screen.blit(
            HEAT_BAR_IMAGE,
            heat_rect,
            # Pass a rect or tuple as the `area` argument.
            # Use the `heat` percentage to calculate the current width.
            (0, 0, heat_rect.w/100*heat, heat_rect.h)
            )

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much, this works EXTREMELY well. Definitely planning to use this going forward in my small game. I really appreciate you taking your time to help me out!

Comment: Hey I was just wondering if you could clear some stuff up for me, first of all:
I was wondering why I cant change the x and y value in this line: HEAT_BAR_IMAGE = pg.Surface((150, 20))
is it referenced somewhere else? additionally, I was wondering what the if loop did at the end, and exactly how the screen.blit calculation worked. Thanks so much again

Comment: The `HEAT_BAR_IMAGE` can be an image with an arbitrary size. You can either create a surface instance like I did in the example or load an image with `pygame.image.load` (which returns a `pygame.Surface` as well). The `for x in range(HEAT_BAR_IMAGE.get_width()):` loop is used to fill the image with a gradient in a rudimentary way and needs to be adjusted for other surface sizes. I'd recommend to look for other solutions if you want to fill your surface with a gradient or just load a ready-made image from your hard disk.

Comment: `heat_rect.w/100*heat` calculates the current width of the surface. `heat` is the percentage of the width, so first divide the width of the image by 100 to get the width of 1 percent and then multiply by `heat` to get the current width.

Comment: Also, the `(150, 20)` argument here `pg.Surface((150, 20))` is the width and height not the position of the Surface. You need to store the position of the surface in a list, tuple, pygame.Rect or vector and then use it as the `dest` argument when you blit the surface.